# Zebra Datawedge 6.2.24 enable/disable not working on Zebra TC75

Tags: android, datawedge

I am trying to get zebra data wedge to enable /disable sample ( https://github.com/darryncampbell/DataWedge-Quick-Suspend-Scanner )  working on zebra TC 75 scanner handset having android version 5.1.1
data wedge version on Zebra TC75 handset is 6.2.24 ( original data wedge version 5.0.17 upgraded to version 6.2.24 by using check system updates). create profile API does not work, so I manually created a profile named "DW Quick Suspend Profile" and enabled this profile. the app is added to associated apps, the barcode input option is checked intent output option is checked. Intent action is specified as com. Darren Campbell.datawedgequicksuspendscanner.action and intent category is specified as android.intent.category.DEFAULT. Broadcast intent is selected for the intended delivery spinner.
but zebra TC75 does send status updates or enable/disable data wedge does not work.
whether anyone got data wedge to enable/disable API or sample code at https://github.com/darryncampbell/DataWedge-Quick-Suspend-Scanner working on Zebra TC 75? if yes what configuration needs to be changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App author here, the reason SUSPEND_PLUGIN and RESUME_PLUGIN are not working for you is that they are not supported in DataWedge 6.2.  DW 6.2 documentation is here: https://techdocs.zebra.com/datawedge/6-2/guide/api/#scannerinputplugin and only shows ENABLE_PLUGIN and DISABLE_PLUGIN as supported.

Comment: My custom app requires disable scanner/ enable scanner functionality.   it is ok even if enable / disable plugin works for datawedge version 6.2. please review custom profile ""DW Quick Suspend Profile" configuration mentioned above and suggest changes if any needed to get enable/disable scanner options get working. During debugging I have added break points in myBroadcastReceiver function but broad cast is not received. looks like communication between datawedge and app is not established . let me know additional information you need from my side

Comment: Ah! Yes, one more thing.  DataWedge 6.2 had a different Intent format, for example 6.2 specified the action as `com.symbol.datawedge.api.ACTION_SCANNERINPUTPLUGIN` whereas the later API (from 6.3 onwards I think) specified the action as `com.symbol.datawedge.api.ACTION`.  There are also changes to the Intent payload to be aware of.  The example app is coded to use the latest API which is probably why it does not work on DW 6.2

Comment: updated code for action to com.symbol.datawedge.api.ACTION_SCANNERINPUTPLUGIN as suggested  and current updated code is added in edited question. it now receives some data in myBroadcastReceiver. pl. take look at updated code and suggest changes to make it work on datawedge 6.2.24

Comment: The code under `case R.id.btnEnablePlugin:` and `case R.id.btnDisablePlugin:` should work but please be aware that `SEND_RESULT` and `COMMAND_IDENTIFIER` are not supported in DataWedge 6.2, so I would not expect any feedback to be given.  `case R.id.btnSuspendPlugin:` and `case R.id.btnResumePlugin:` will not work with DataWedge 6.2 nor will any code to retrieve the version.  I recommend using https://github.com/darryncampbell/DataWedge-API-Exerciser/blob/darryncampbell_repo_backup/app/src/main/java/com/zebra/datawedgeexerciser/MainActivity.java#L168 as a better source for the 6.2 APIs

Comment: I will refer  relevant code 6.2 version from  https://github.com/darryncampbell/DataWedge-API-Exerciser/blob/darryncampbell_repo_backup/app/src/main/java/com/zebra/datawedgeexerciser/MainActivity.java and get back

Comment: as per suggestion got it worked using  api supported in datawedge version 6.0 and 6.2 only.

Comment: can we enable and disable profile? .. if i disable plugin the other app who is using datawedge can't use it ..